# Is there the semantic difference between two sentences?

Tags: word-choice

> The approximate time when we should meet is 5 o’clock.

> Approximately 5 o’clock is the time when we should meet.

Is there the semantic difference between “approximate” and “approximately”?

“Approximately the approximate time when we should meet is 5 o’clock”
is correct if two are different?

Comment: There is no semantic difference, but it's odd to begin the sentence with _approximately_ because it emphasises the approximation instead of the time. Better to say "Five o'clock - approximately - is the time..."

Answer (score 1):

There is a grammatical difference between approximate and approximately.

Approximate is an adjective.  It modifies a noun, in this case the noun "time"

Approximately is an adverb, it modifies the numeral "5".

However both sentences give the same idea, and so "mean the same". But neither is well expressed. There are better ways to express the same idea.

> We should meet at approximately 5 o'clock.

It is the same idea; it is shorter; and it is more active, with "we" as the main subject.

Your final version (with approximately approximate) is not idiomatic. It is correct grammar (it would benefit from a comma after "approximately"), but pointlessly repetitive. Don't talk like that.